# Is it possible to horizontally scroll with user-scalable=no?

Tags: css, viewport

I am trying to display an HTML table on mobile devices and I have the following CSS settings for the page content:

```
.page-content {
    display: flex,
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 900px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I am setting the viewport width dynamically for mobile devices so that it does not auto zoom in/out on the display.

```
window.onload = function() {
    let vp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
    if (screen.width < 830) {
        let w = 'user-scalable=no, width=' + screen.width;
        vp.setAttribute('content', w);
    }
}
```

While I can vertically scroll through the table rows, I cannot horizontally scroll to see some columns that are outside of the device screen width. If I remove `user-scalable=no` from the code, I can horizontally scroll but in that case the content is automatically zoomed in or out which I do not want.

Is it possible to enable horizontal scrolling with `user-scalable=no`?

Comment: Why u disable scaling for user? If the user wants to zoom in, it would be more userfriendly if u allow him. So i don't really see advantages to disable that.

Comment: In some cases, it leaves some blank spaces on the display or it zooms too much sometimes.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you allow user-scalable but provide a maximum-scale attribute. So the user can scale but it don't zooms too much.